# I need to show this data from Parser in a listview, how do I?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I need to show this data in a listview, it's relational data, I already know how to re-emerge, what I do not know is how it shows it, I'm doing it inside an activity.

final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvComentario);
        **final String[][] values = {new String[]{" linda", " bonita"}};**

```
    final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < values[0].length; ++i) {
        list.add(values[0][i]);
    }

    final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);


    comentario = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text_comentario);
    botaoSalvar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_salvar);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    obID = i.getStringExtra("imagem");

    //exibirComentario();



    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("comentario");
    query.whereEqualTo("parentesco", obID);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        public void done(List<ParseObject> commentList, ParseException e) {

            if (e == null) {

                Log.d("score", "no doctor available: ");


            } else {

                Log.w("Parse query", e.getMessage());
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Comment: You didn't specify which data you receive from parse.

Comment: the data I'm getting from analysis, are text that a user is commented on a post

Comment: Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: After getting data from parse create an adapter and set it to your ListView. check this :http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: I already have the logic, what I can not or do not know is to show this parser data in the list view.

Comment: I updated to show how you did it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set adapter after you receive data from parse.

```
final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvComentario); 

ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("comentario");
query.whereEqualTo("parentesco", obID);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

    public void done(List<ParseObject> commentList, ParseException e) {

        if (e == null) {

            Log.d("score", "no doctor available: ");


        } else {

            Log.w("Parse query", e.getMessage());
            //Use your custom adapter according to your comment list or design
            final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, commentList);
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }
```